# Which settings • preferences • preset to use in Adobe Premiere when exporting in QuickTime (.mov) format to avoid lines?

Tags: premiere, quicktime

My workflow:

1. Record footage on iPhone
2. Copy to Mac
3. Add to Adobe Premiere
4. When dragging iPhone clips "change sequence settings"
5. Edit / Cut / Transitions / all that fancy stuff
6. Nest clips
7. Speed / Duration to something "instagram-able" (say 25 seconds)
8. Speed keyframes so initially and on exit it's in real-life speed
9. Add some music
10. Export media as QuickTime (.mov) so that later I can synchronise with iPhone
11. Set maximum bitrate to something really big (30Mbps) so that quality is preserved
12. Post to Instagram *(1 hour of effort for each post)*

### Now...

[image]

**What am I doing wrong?**

What switch / option / settings / preferences would allow me to avoid... *(see image above for a still frame)*

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have interlaced turned on. Try a different method of frame blending